# Apache2 on Debian, fresh install, cant get rid of default

Tags: apache, apache2, dns, debian, vhosts

I installed my Debian 6 on my server, and somehow I cannot get rid of the default configurations. I still get pointed to `/var/www` instead of the directory I actually want.

Is there something special I need to do in debian? For example remove the "default" settings? I have even tried not to create hosts through Webmin, and it says that it has been configured correctly, however I cannot access it.

As I do in xampp I try to configure my root for my domain through a vhost, now what happens is that it gives me Forbidden error when I try to open the page. And sometimes it gives me /var/www if I configure sub-domains.

The folder exists that I try to access, and I even tried to set it to `chmod 777 -R folder`.

I'd like some input, and also some advice on where I can read logs about this, as nothing shows up in apache error log.

And I keep getting these when I restart apache:

> [Fri Nov 18 23:36:42 2011] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
>
> [Fri Nov 18 23:36:42 2011] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts

Comment: Is this an issue? [Fri Nov 18 23:37:47 2011] [error] [client {IP}] client denied by server configuration: /htdocs/svn/cswb/timetracker/trunk/timetracker-web/
[Fri Nov 18 23:37:47 2011] [error] [client {IP}] client denied by server configuration: /htdocs/svn/cswb/timetracker/trunk/timetracker-web/favicon.ico

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have multiple problems.

If you have virtual hosts enabled, then the default vhost config will be /etc/apache2/site-enabled/000-default.  Try starting with only that one host enabled.  Are you able to get it to work with the DocumentRoot you want, serving content from there with no errors?  Make sure it's working correctly before you add in other hosts.

If you have errors with just that one vhost, post its config in your question.

Comment: So I got a bit further and I am now able to get to the pages I want. However when they render, they render by printing out all the code! How do I make the php compile this?

Comment: So this being the instance where I try to access a subdomain. for example mysubdomain.mymaindomain.com, then the PHP would get printed out as text. However if I enter mymaindomain.com or www.mymaindomain.com it works great.